# Integrate$ \int \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4}{[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+\cos(x)}} dx$

Tags: integration

In my previous post I had some typo that caused putting on hold the question. I deleted that question and here is the correct one.
Integrate:

$$ \int \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4}{[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+ \cos(x)}} dx$$

I was working on integrability of $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a+\cos(x)}}$ and I found $ \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4}{[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+ \cos(x)}} dx$ is integrable. I dont think it can be integrarted by part.

How about if the question is:

Integrate:

$$ \int \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4 Cos (x)+4a}{[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+ \cos(x)}} dx$$

I will give the solution  after few answers.

Comment: This seems to be a good candidate for some elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4 Cos (x)+4a}{[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+ \cos(x)}} dx$$

$4\times \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4 Cos (x)+4a}{4[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+ \cos(x)}} =4\times\frac{2Sin^2(x) Cos(x)+4(a+Cos(x))}{[\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}]Sin^2x}=4\times\frac{(1/2)Sin^2(x)Cos(x)+(a+Cos(x))}{[\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}]Sin^2x}=4\times[\frac{Cos(x)}{2\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}}+\frac{\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}}{Sin^2(x)}]$

We may write:

$\frac{Cos(x)}{2\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}}=-[(\sqrt{a+Cosx})'] Cotan (x)$

$\frac{\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}}{Sin^2(x)}=-[\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}](Cotan(x))'$

⇒$$ \int \frac{\sin(x) \sin(2x)+4 Cos (x)+4a}{[\sin^2(x)]\sqrt{a+ \cos(x)}} dx=-4[\sqrt{a+Cos(x)}] Cotan(x)$$